# How select the last active cell?

Tags: vba, function, cell, key-value, helper

Instead of selecting cell A1 at the end I want to select the last active cell. That is, where I clicked with the cursor. What would be the sentence?

```
function OrderMacro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B3:AF41').activate()
  .sort({column: 32, ascending: false});
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Are You sure this is VBA language?

Answer (score 0):

in VBA it can be so:

```
Sub OrderMacro()
Dim o As Object
    Set o = Selection
    Range("B3:AF41").Activate
    'do something
    o.Select
End Sub
```

> Property Selection As Object
>       read-only
>       Member of Excel.Application